# Access Denied when Creating Remote Powershell session for Exchange 2013. But not always

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013, remoting

Access Denied error is thrown sometimes when connecting to an Exchange Server 2003 SP1 server. The cmd-let used to connect is:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$sessOpt = New-SessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
$credent = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession -SessionOption $sessOpt -Credential $cred -Authentication Kerberos -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionURI http://ex1/Powershell
```

Error:

```
System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server ex1.domain.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic
```

The above error is thrown for few attempts and after sometimes it works. The same cycle repeats. Unable to find why the Access is denied for few attempts. Tested in different machines with same result.

Comment: Can you start the Cmdlet with the `-Verbose` parameter and post back the results?

Comment: @JohandeHaan Sorry for delayed reply. There are not Verbose prints found in the result.

Comment: Ever found a solution to this?